# Composer phar package not found

Tags: php, composer-php

I am trying to create a new composer library package. 
I created the composer.json file using the

`composer.phar create-project xlix vendor/xlix/xlix 0.3`

command.

In the filesystem the file composer.json exists under `vendor/xlix/xlix` and for testing purposes I copied it to `vendor/xlix`.

The composer.json file content is the following:

```
{
    "name": "xlix/xlix",
    "type": "library",
    "description": "XLIX package",
    "keywords": ["core"],
    "homepage": "http://myhomepage",
    "license": "GPL",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Florian Kasper",
            "email": "florian.kasper@mymail"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.2.4"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0" : {
            "Xlix\\Bundle" : "lib/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "1.0"
        }
    }
}
```

Then I tried the following commands:

```
git:(master) ✗  php composer.phar require xlix/xlix
git:(master) ✗  php composer.phat require vendor/xlix
...

git:(master) ✗  php composer.phar install vendor/xlix
git:(master) ✗  php composer.phar install xlix/xlix
...
```

Every time the same output:

```
Please provide a version constraint for the xlix/xlix requirement: *
composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package xlix/xlix could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.
```

In my **ROOTDIR/composer.json** file the package is registered in the require section.

```
"jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.2.*",
"jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.1.*",
"kriswallsmith/assetic": "1.1.*@dev",
"xlix/xlix": ">=0.*"
```

Now I am on the edge of despair an don't know what to do anymore.

Question:

Are there any mistakes I've made or is there anything i missed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Packages live on the internet, not on your filesystem.

Composer searches by default for a package called `xlix/xlix` on [packagist](https://packagist.org/) and that [does not exists](https://packagist.org/search/?q=xlix%2Fxlix). You can add more package repositories by using the `repositories` configuration, more about that in [the documentation](http://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#repositories).

So, in order to require your package with composer you need to upload your `xlix` directory somewhere.

---

I don't see what you are trying to do in the `lxix` directory? You are in the `lxix` package, why do you want to require it in the same package? It looks like you don't understand what those commands do and how composer works. Maybe a good read in their own documentation -- or some other tutorials about Composer (like the one on [nettuts+](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/easy-package-management-with-composer/)) --  will help you to get a better understanding of composer.